# How do I fix this importing error in pycharm?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm

I recently started using python and pycharm, just to fool around a bit with it. But I am running into a problem with importing the sklearn module. All other modules work just fine, only not this one (sklearn) is a pain. The modules that I try to import are the following:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn import svm, neighbors
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier, RandomForestClassifier
```

Running this gives the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Luck Slijpen/PycharmProjects/Stock data manipulation/Processing for ML.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .fixes import np_version
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    import scipy.stats
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 384, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 179, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from ._procrustes import procrustes
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_procrustes.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import orthogonal_procrustes
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 195, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Users\Luck Slijpen\PycharmProjects\Stock data manipulation\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 215, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have been stuck at this for a while and any help is appriciated! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a very high chance this is a PYTHONPATH issue where your pyCharm is unable to talk to the correct python version (or virtual environment) that has all the required libraries installed. You may need to configure pyCharm by going to *preferences > project > Project Interpreter* and then selecting the correct binary of python

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comment. When I select my project interpreter, I also get only one option in the dropdownbox and that is the 3.7 Pyhton version just like you. or should I manually add another interpreter, so yes do you have any link on how to do so?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes you will have to do add another interpreter . More info can be found https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html

Answer (score 0):

I would go here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html
Check your installation and re-install if necessary. 
the site also states that if Numpy or Scipy were recompiled from source (not sure if that is your situation) you may have issues.

Comment: Paul, thank you for your comment. I tried everything that is mentioned on the website you attached. Unfortunately, I still get the same error running the commands.